# C database program can't find 1st input. Why?

Tags: c, search, input

I made a program, which stores student id, name, surname and marks. This program has no faulty but it can't find first input.

ie.

```
input file;
23915746455 James   Doe 1   
23915741327 John    Doe 2   
23915741842 Henny   Fluffy  3
```

My code will find John and Henny in ID and name search but it won't find James. What's wrong with my code? 1st input won't be searched.

My full code is here;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Student
{
    long long int id;
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    int mark;
} student;

void
storeRecord()
{
    FILE *fp;

    printf("\nEnter Student Details:\n\nID number: ");
    scanf("%lld",&student.id);

    printf("\nName:");
    scanf("%19s",student.firstname);

    printf("\nSurname:");
    scanf("%19s",student.lastname);

    printf("\nMark(0 - 100 integer) : ");
    scanf("%d",&student.mark);

    fp = fopen("studentfile.txt","a+"); /* check if the file was opened */
    if (fp == NULL)
        return;
    fprintf(fp, "\n%lld\t%s\t%s\t%d\t", 
        student.id, 
        student.firstname, 
        student.lastname, 
        student.mark);
    fclose(fp);

    printf("A student record has been added successfully...\n");
    getchar();
}

int
compareStudentsById(struct Student lhs, struct Student rhs)
{
    return (lhs.id == rhs.id);
}

int
compareStudentsByName(struct Student lhs, struct Student rhs)
{
    return (strcmp(lhs.firstname, rhs.firstname) == 0);
}

void
printStudent()
{
    printf("\nThe record is found.\n");
    printf("\nID: %lld\nName: %s\nSurname: %s\nMark: %d \n",
        student.id,
        student.firstname,
        student.lastname,
        student.mark
    );
}

void
searchStudent(int(*compare)(struct Student,struct Student), const char *const name, long long int id)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int   found;
    int   matches;


    if (name != NULL)
        printf("Searching record with Name = %s.\n", name);
    if (id != -1)
        printf("Searching record with ID   = %lld.\n", id);

    found = 0;
    fp    = fopen("studentfile.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("IO error\n");
        return;
    }

    matches = fscanf(fp,"\n%lld\t%s\t%s\t%d\t", 
        &student.id, 
        student.firstname, 
        student.lastname, 
        &student.mark);

    do
    {
        struct Student other;

        if (name != NULL)
            strcpy(other.firstname, name);

        other.id = id;
        matches  = fscanf(fp,"\n%lld\t%s\t%s\t%d\t", 
            &student.id, 
            student.firstname, 
            student.lastname, 
            &student.mark);

        if (matches == 4)
            found = (compare(student, other) != 0);

    } while ((matches == 4) && (found == 0));

    if (found != 0)
        printStudent(); 
    else
        printf("Not found...\n");

    getchar();
}

void
searchStudentByName()
{
    char studentname[20];

    printf("\nEnter student first name: ");
    scanf("%19s", studentname);

    searchStudent(compareStudentsByName, studentname, -1);
}

void
searchStudentById()
{
    long long int id;

    printf("\nEnter ID: ");
    scanf("%lld", &id);

    searchStudent(compareStudentsById, NULL, id);
}

int main()
{
    int choice;

    choice = 0;
    while (choice != 4)
    {
        printf("\n\tC PROGRAM OF STUDENT DATABASE SYSTEM"); 
        printf("\n1 -> Store a new record in database\n");
        printf("2 -> Search a student record by Student First Name\n");
        printf("3 -> Search a student record by ID\n");
        printf("4 -> Quit Student Database");
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");

        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
        case  1:
            storeRecord();
            break;
        case 2:
            searchStudentByName();
            break;
        case 3:
            searchStudentById();
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time to lean how to use a debugger.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I'm already using the debugger. There is no error while compiling. :<

Comment: A debugger is used to examine running code, variables, etc. It is not a compiler.  Learning how to debug is a critical skill.

Comment: You do a `fscanf` then you start a `do-while` loop where you do another `fscanf` that just discards the results of the first search. That's why you loose the first record.

Comment: @WonderfulC - Then it is time to learn _what_ a debugger is.

Comment: @void_ptr can you proivde me any worthy source?

Comment: @WonderfulC - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger

Comment: `man perror`.  In particular, when you detect an error when opening a file: `if( fp == NULL ) { perror(path);}`.  Error messages belong on stderr, and they should be useful.  Using printf fails both criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the first `fscanf` the one outside the `while` loop, its scanning the first line of the file.

A copy of your code fixed

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Student
{
    long long int id;
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    int mark;
} student;

void
storeRecord()
{
    FILE *fp;

    printf("\nEnter Student Details:\n\nID number: ");
    scanf("%lld",&student.id);

    printf("\nName:");
    scanf("%19s",student.firstname);

    printf("\nSurname:");
    scanf("%19s",student.lastname);

    printf("\nMark(0 - 100 integer) : ");
    scanf("%d",&student.mark);

    fp = fopen("studentfile.txt","a+"); /* check if the file was opened */
    if (fp == NULL)
        return;
    fprintf(fp, "\n%lld\t%s\t%s\t%d\t", 
        student.id, 
        student.firstname, 
        student.lastname, 
        student.mark);
    fclose(fp);

    printf("A student record has been added successfully...\n");
    getchar();
}

int
compareStudentsById(struct Student lhs, struct Student rhs)
{
    return (lhs.id == rhs.id);
}

int
compareStudentsByName(struct Student lhs, struct Student rhs)
{
    return (strcmp(lhs.firstname, rhs.firstname) == 0);
}

void
printStudent()
{
    printf("\nThe record is found.\n");
    printf("\nID: %lld\nName: %s\nSurname: %s\nMark: %d \n",
        student.id,
        student.firstname,
        student.lastname,
        student.mark
    );
}

void
searchStudent(int(*compare)(struct Student,struct Student), const char *const name, int id)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int   found;
    int   matches;


    if (name != NULL)
        printf("Searching record with Name = %s.\n", name);
    if (id != -1)
        printf("Searching record with ID   = %d.\n", id);

    found = 0;
    fp    = fopen("studentfile.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("IO error\n");
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        struct Student other;

        if (name != NULL)
            strcpy(other.firstname, name);

        other.id = id;
        matches  = fscanf(fp,"\n%lld\t%s\t%s\t%d\t", 
            &student.id, 
            student.firstname, 
            student.lastname, 
            &student.mark);

        if (matches == 4)
            found = (compare(student, other) != 0);

    } while ((matches == 4) && (found == 0));

    if (found != 0)
        printStudent(); 
    else
        printf("Not found...\n");

    getchar();
}

void
searchStudentByName()
{
    char studentname[20];

    printf("\nEnter student first name: ");
    scanf("%19s", studentname);

    searchStudent(compareStudentsByName, studentname, -1);
}

void
searchStudentById()
{
    int id;

    printf("\nEnter student first name: ");
    scanf("%d", &id);

    searchStudent(compareStudentsByName, NULL, id);
}

int main()
{
    int choice;

    choice = 0;
    while (choice != 4)
    {
        printf("\n\tC PROGRAM OF STUDENT DATABASE SYSTEM"); 
        printf("\n1 -> Store a new record in database\n");
        printf("2 -> Search a student record by Student First Name\n");
        printf("3 -> Search a student record by ID\n");
        printf("4 -> Quit Student Database");
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");

        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
        case  1:
            storeRecord();
            break;
        case 2:
            searchStudentByName();
            break;
        case 3:
            searchStudentById();
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```